# Explanation of a step in a solution.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, outer-measure

The problem and the solution are given below:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1-In the fourth line from below, the author used that $$\cup I_{n} \subset l(I_{n}),$$ but I do not understand why?

2-What is the importance of assuming that $E$ is a bounded set?

Could anyone explain this to me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: For 2) Can you maybe also post the definition referenced? Is it only valid for bounded sets? I can imagine that for any unbounded set $A$ we have $m(A) = \infty$. The statement then is trivial because for any unbounded set you can always an superset with measure $\infty$.

Comment: If you are working with outer measure, one possible definition  is given by: $$ m^{*}(A):=\inf \left \{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell(I_k) \mid  A \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}I_k\right\}  \textrm{ where } \ell(I)=\begin{cases}\infty \quad& I \textrm{ unbounded} \\ b-a \quad& I\textrm{ bounded}  \end{cases} . 
$$

Comment: @ViktorGlombik the definition I am using is given in the above comment by Charles Seife. ..... what about my first question?